# Check if a file/URL exists on Sharepoint Online

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-online

I'm looking for a way of checking if a file exists on SharePoint Online.

Our Sharepoint on premise was moved to Sharepoint Online, since that my code doesn't work.

Existing recommendations don't work. I've been looking for a solution (google) for couple of weeks with no success.

HTTPRequest always returns `.Status="OK"` and `.StatusText="200"` even for a file that does not exist in SharePoint folder.

The code below shows what I have tried so far (in many combinations, but result is always the same)

```
Sub Test_WinHTTPRequest()

    Set HttpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With HttpRequest
        .Open "GET", "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/wt-teams-CServices/WAN%20Fin/FY19-20/test_file.xlsx"
'       .Open "GET", "http://company.sharepoint.com/sites/wt-teams-CServices/WAN%20Fin/FY19-20/test_file123.xlsx"
'       .Open "GET", "http://company.sharepoint.com/sites/wt-teams-CServices/WAN Fin/FY19-20/test_file123.xlsx"
        .Send
        st = .Status
        stt = .StatusText
        rt = .ResponseText
    End With
    Debug.Print rt, st, stt

End Sub
```

The same situation with MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 object

Whatever file name I use in URL, HTTPRequest always returns "URL exist".
.ResponceText returns huge output with some HTML code which is exactly the same for any filename I used in URL.

In Internet Explorer or Windows explorer, if I paste the URL with non-existing filename, returns an error as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

did You consider using SharePoint REST Api methods to get the file from folder by server relative url? something like:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files('{file_name}')/$value
```

for more request calls that could meet Your needs please check -> [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

I hope this will put You on the right track :)

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I possibly need more detailed explanation how to use it. First look made me really confused by this. Thanks again.

Comment: I may have to add, that the code for opening a file works pretty well. But I need to check the existence of several files and open only one of them.
That code uses standard syntax like: `Workbooks.Open Filename:=URLtoFile`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for checking whether the URL exists or not...

```
Private Function urlExists(url As String) As Boolean ' Reference to Microsoft XML V3 required
    Dim Request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30
    On Error Resume Next
    With Request
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send
        urlExists = IIf(.Status = 200, True, False)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: It doesnt work. This is one of variations I have tried. The result is the same - it returns ,Status = 200 for any URL including for non-existing file,

Comment: Ah - hadn't picked up on the difference between 'Sharepoint' and 'Sharepoint Online'. Can you try and download the file and see if it errors? although not an ideal solution...

Comment: Downloading works well with no efforts: `Workbooks.Open Filename:=URLtoFile` But I cant afford opening and close for more than 10 files.
Eventually , if I dont find a solution, I will go this way, but dont want to really.